# How does one block another key's input (LShift) while holding specific key (RMB)?

Tags: scripting, logitech

As simple as possible, while holding RMB I want my Logitech software to block the input of left shift. So to be exact if I'm holding left Shift and I press and hold RMB I want to block left shift input, If press left shift while holding RMB down i'd also like it to ignore the input until RMB is released.

I tried reading multiple websites and have a headache, tried reading between the lines of different similar ideas but haven't figured it out.... thus seeking help since I've read a few other post ppl had help with.

Comment: Does `ReleaseKey("lshift")` solve your problem?

Comment: Imma keep it 100% real with you, idk. I dont know how to write the code first of all for logitech to understand. how would it be wrote? my expertise in life is as a mechanic and cnc machinist (direct motion not g code). how would that line of code understand to do that only on press of rmb and while holding? and once released would shift go back to its function if currently being held?

Comment: ok, what is your logitech software?  LGS or GHub?